# Java: Is there any short combination to convert array of primitive to List & receive "printable" version?

Tags: java, arrays

```
int[] arrc = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
System.out.println(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arrc)));
```

prints address, but i desire to use toString as in ArrayList.

Is it possible ?

Comment: ArrayList.toString() should print nicely, too, though

Comment: @Thilo, true, although it's a bit more verbose than `Arrays`' `toString()` methods. Also, if the code is executed often, and the array is large, creating new instances of `ArrayList`s might slow the app down.

Comment: @Bart K. Sure. I just wanted to clarify what he meant by "prints address" while the code appears to print something more legible.

Comment: @Thilo, now that you mention it, it does not print anything legible after all (I thought so too at first). Since Arrays.asList(...) only takes Objects, the inherited toString() (`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`) of the primitive array is printed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

// ...

int[] arrc = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrc));
```

Note that the `asList(...)` does not take an array of primitive `int`'s but takes `Object`s instead, that's why you see an address-like String appear.

So, doing:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
List list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

results in the same as doing:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(array);
```

Both result in a List that has one element in it: an array of primitive `int`s.

(only that `Arrays.asList(...)` returns a List that cannot be modified...)

Comment: Re: asList. That's bad. So what happens is that a List with a single element gets created, that element being an int[]. Auto(un-)boxing fail...

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print the array:

```
Arrays.toString( arrc )
```

If you want to turn an `int[]` into a List, `Arrays.asList` does *not* work, unfortunately (it only works with `Object[]`):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(arrc.length);
for (int a: arrc)
   list.add(a);

System.out.println(list); // prints nicely now
```

Comment: @Thilo, note that since Java 1.5, `asList(...)` takes a *vararg* of Objects, not an array of Objects. So you can also provide a single Object, or even something like: `asList(1, 2, 3)` (the int's get boxed to `Integer`s!)

Comment: Yes, but he already has an int[]. unlikely that the numbers are hard-coded in the source.

Comment: true, but since you said "it only works with `Object[]`" I wanted to let you know it was `Object...` instead of `Object[]`.

Answer (score 1):

use Arrays.[toString](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29)(arrc)

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache Commons Lang as your main library after SDK

```
System.out.println("An object: " + ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(anObject));
```

Comment: I don't see the benefit of using a 3rd party library for such an easy task. If blackliteon already has that Apache Commons Jar in his classpath, sure, but adding it just for creating a printable String of an array, which is easily done by the Arrays class, is IMO overkill.

Comment: It might be worth having a general-purpose 3rd-party library like commons-collections or guava on your classpath anyway, because in most non-trivial projects it will come in useful for other tasks too.

Answer (score 0):

using [Dollar](http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar) should be simple:

```
int[] ary = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
String string = $(ary).toString(); // wrapping Arrays.toString()
```

alternatively you can convert the int array to `List` then use the `toString` method :

```
List<Integer> list = $(ary).toList();
```

please note that `list` is an `ArrayList`: you can even specify which concrete class should be used simply passing a `List` implementation (it will work with any `List` implementation with a no-args constructor):

```
List<Integer> linkedList = $(ary).toList(LinkedList.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Ints.asList` from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;

// ...

int[] arrc = {1, 2, 3, 4};
List<Integer> list = Ints.asList(arrc);
System.out.println(list);
// Output: "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```